# RabbitMQ is configured to use a custom epmd port, but the server still starts on the default epmd process

Tags: rabbitmq

I have rabbitmq versions 3.7.7, with erlang 21.0.

I have started a epmd deamon on, let's say, port 20000.

I have also set the ERL_EPMD_PORT=20000 on the 
rabbitmq-env.conf.

Now when I start ./rabbitmq-server, it still start a new epmd process on port 4369 (the default) and starts a node under that. So under epmd -port 20000 no rabbitmq node is active.

However, when I try to control the node, rabbitmqctl status DOES look under the epmd process under port 20000, and thus finds nothing.

1. How can I make sure rabbitmq-server uses the custom epmd port
2. Why are rabbitmq-server and rabbitmqctl using a different rabbitmq-env.conf file/environment?

Comment: This is a legitimate bug that you should report here: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues

Thanks!

Comment: @LukeBakken I'm not really into the rabbitmq community, so I won't file a bug. If you want to go ahead, be my guest.

Comment: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/1709 - thanks for taking the time to report the issue. For future reference, the RabbitMQ team actively monitors [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users) and only sometimes checks stack overflow.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to work on this. Great to see such an active community!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I ended up writing (after a struggle of one day to get it working the 'nice' way):

> export ERL_EPMD_PORT=20000 in sbin/rabbitmq-defaults

Still I find it a lame answer, but is does work! Stored here for future reference and others with the same question